# pivotslicer connected to multiple pivotcharts

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, charts, pivot-table

Can I connect my pivotslicer to multiple pivotcharts, but on different category levels, so If for example I have a categorytree that goes:

Department
--> Section

If I choose "Section A" Then I can have one chart display Section A data, and 1 chart displaying the Department of Section A Data (the parent of section A)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can create a pivot chart that breaks the data down by section. Create another pivot chart that breaks the data down by department.

Add a pivot slicer to the first chart for the section. Then click the data table for the second chart and click "Insert Slicer > Slicer Connections". Select the tick box next to "section".

That way, the two pivots will show the same grand total. The first will show the section only, the second chart will show the parent departments for the selected section.

Here is a [link to a sample file](https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=FE479525195477F7!509&authkey=!ADMfsZh7cNz_OcE)

Comment: I'm trying to figure it out, but I'm having some trouble - a sample file would be much appreciated

Comment: I added a link to a sample file above.

Comment: Hi again - I got it working, but it actually didn't solve my problem. The issue is that the slicer is more granular than I want graph 2 to be, so instead of "zooming in" and taking child-data also. I want to "zoom out" and take parent data based on the child that is selected through the slicer

Comment: in other words: department is above section in my data

Comment: Hmm. The method and sample I posted do what (I think) you describe in your question. But apparently it's not the result you desire. How about taking the guess work out of the answer attempts. Post a data sample and mock up the desired results manually. Then we at least know what to aim for.